# Fill Dataset From sqlite

Tags: xamarin.android

How can this function be modified.
I want to use it to fill in the dataset from sqllite.

error

[image]

```
 public void fillDATASET( DataSet ds, string tablename, string query)
        {
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
        "Department.db3");
              var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
             using (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(query, conn))// error conn 
            {
                using (var DataAdapterd = new SqliteDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    ds.Clear();
                    DataAdapterd.Fill(ds, tablename);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you use two different libraries.

```
var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
```

here you used the method in **sqlite-net-pcl** nuget,

```
Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(query, conn)
```

here you want use the method in **System.Data.SQLite.Core** nuget.

So you need to use a unified.

For example(use **System.Data.SQLite.Core** nuget):

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;

public void fillDATASET(DataSet ds, string tablename, string query)
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
    "Department.db3");
        var conn = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn))// error conn 
        {
            using (var DataAdapterd = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                ds.Clear();
                DataAdapterd.Fill(ds, tablename);
            }
        }
    }
```